# How do I add this counter API to my clickHandler so it can count each click with its corresponding value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach, onclicklistener

In my html I have a form with 4 radio buttons. Each radio button represents an option the user can submit.

I have set up an event listener that listens for a radio button change event:

```
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']"),function(radio)
{
        radio.addEventListener("change", handleRadioClick);
});
```

And this is how my click handler looks like:

```
function handleRadioClick()   //this code happens when user selects this radio button
{
  var label = document.querySelector("[for='"+this.id+"']");
  //execute more stuff here
}
```

I now need to add a Doubleclick counter API

```
    Enabler.counter('Option 1 was clicked'); //i.e.
```

so we can track what option has been clicked.

**How would I go about accomplishing this?** Thanks so much for any tips!

*Note: Plain JS suggestions only please. Thanks!*

Comment: You should just use `this.labels[0]` instead of that selector

Comment: Are you asking how to place `Enabler.counter(…)` in your `handleRadioClick` function?

Comment: Hi yes, I am not quite sure how I would place the 4 counters, so they would track the respective radio button's option on click. Thanks

Comment: `this.value+" was clicked"`?